# LWC Datatable in a multi-currency org: Dollar sign $ appears for a moment on Cell change for non-dollar currency

Tags: datatable, currency, sign, lwc, lightning

The column definition is:

```
{
  "columns": [
    {
      "cellAttributes": {
        "alignment": "left"
      },
      "editable": false,
      "fieldName": "aiq_BandNumber__c",
      "label": "Tier Band",
      "sortable": false,
      "typeAttributes": {}
    },
    {
      "cellAttributes": {
        "alignment": "left"
      },
      "editable": true,
      "fieldName": "aiq_LowerBound__c",
      "label": "Lower Bound",
      "sortable": false,
      "type": "currency",
      "typeAttributes": {
        "currencyCode": {
          "fieldName": "CurrencyIsoCode"
        },
        "currencyDisplayAs": "code",
        "step": "0.01",
        "maximumFractionDigits": "2"
      }
    },
    {
      "cellAttributes": {
        "alignment": "left"
      },
      "editable": false,
      "fieldName": "aiq_UpperBound__c",
      "label": "Upper Bound",
      "sortable": false,
      "type": "currency",
      "typeAttributes": {
        "currencyCode": {
          "fieldName": "CurrencyIsoCode"
        },
        "currencyDisplayAs": "code",
        "step": "0.01",
        "maximumFractionDigits": "2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[Datatable with multicurrency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaHTc.png)

[Once we click to edit cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cyNL.png)

Once editing a cell Dollar Sign appears for a moment ($), no matter which currency code is (USD, EUR, PLN etc.) and then Currency displays how it should

Nobody knows how to avoid that?

Many thanks